# How do I cancel a touch action on Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

Say I have an button with a `touchEnd` event listener. If I touch the button, slide my finger out of the button and then release touch, I'd like to "cancel" the touch event.

This behaves correctly if I do the following using `onClick`:

```
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target === this) {
    // Do something
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't work with "touchEnd" because `event.target` points to the *originating* element (`buttonElement` in this case), not to the element where I released touch.

Is there a better generic way to do this besides doing something like setting a flag on "touchMove"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the touch events: touchstart, touchmove, touchcancel, touchend. See the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

Regardless, I don't think I'd try to cancel the event. On the event I would check the location of the "cursor" (finger) and if it was outside of the area, just not fire the function.

Comment: This is the proper way to do this. touchcancel is only called if something happens like the user receives a call or push notification.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of how touchCancel is triggered, hence "cancel" in quotes. So basically there's no way around keeping track of some state outside the event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I'm searching how to do the same thing, and I wrote a code that works, and if anyone need this later.

I just canceling the default action if the touch move. Works pretty well on my WebApp, and the feedback is much better than dealing with mouseup and mousedown events, on mobile safari is too slow.

```
var moved=false;

function touchstart(){
    moved=false;
    //highlight button for feedback
}

function touchmove(){
    moved=true;
}

function touchend(){
    //undo-highlight the button

    if(moved) touchcanceled();
    else action();
}

function touchcanceled(){
    //user just flicked the button,
    //probably scrolling the view
}

function action(){
    alert("You triggered me!");
}
```

*add this functions to theirs respective event listeners

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago but I just wanted to add my 2c worth since there's no accepted answer for this question yet.

touchCancel isn't very reliable on the mobile platforms at the moment.

See: 
http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/12/23/different-ways-to-trigger-touchcancel-in-mobile-browsers/

Alternatively you could go the route of writing your own sort-of event overlay like what's done in [Hammer.JS](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/)

That way you can determine the type of gesture before you cancel.